How to get the running terminal emulator while running a shell?
I am building an alternative system information reporter like neofetch, it works fine but there is one problem.
It cannot get the current terminal emulator while running bash.
I tried these commands:
readlink "/proc/$(cat /proc/$(echo $$)/stat|cut -d ' ' -f 4)/exe"
ps -o comm= -p $(ps -o ppid= -p $$)

They work perfectly fine when executed normally, but when I put them in a bash script, it just returns bash or /usr/bin/bash.
I want to find a command that always reports the terminal emulator, not the shell.
Here is the full code if you want:
#!/bin/sh

# yes. no logos. because why not?

# source the config file
if [ "$colorsoff" = "" ]; then
    colorsoff=0
fi

[ -e /etc/betterfetchrc ] && . /etc/betterfetchrc 2> /dev/null
[ -e ~/.betterfetchrc ] && . ~/.betterfetchrc 2> /dev/null

CURRENT_VERSION_FILE="/etc/betterfetch-version"  # Path to the file containing the current version
REMOTE_VERSION_URL="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sctech-tr/betterfetch/main/betterfetch-version"

# Fetch the remote version from the URL
REMOTE_VERSION=$(curl -s $REMOTE_VERSION_URL)

# Read the current version from the version file
if [ -f "$CURRENT_VERSION_FILE" ]; then
  CURRENT_VERSION=$(cat "$CURRENT_VERSION_FILE")
else
  echo "error: current version file not found."
  exit 1
fi

# Compare the remote version with the current version
if [ "$REMOTE_VERSION" != "$CURRENT_VERSION" ]; then
  echo "betterfetch ($REMOTE_VERSION) is available! you are currently on version $CURRENT_VERSION."
  exit 0
fi



# the meat and potatoes, actual fetch

# only set these if they are not already set by the config file
[ -z "$os" ] && . /etc/os-release 2>/dev/null || export os="Unknown"
[ -z "$host" ] && host=$(cat /proc/sys/kernel/hostname)
[ -z "$kernel" ] && kernel=$(sed "s/version // ; s/ (.*//" /proc/version)
[ -z "$uptime" ] && uptime=$(uptime -p 2>/dev/null | sed "s/up //")
[ -z "$shell" ] && shell=$(printf "$SHELL" | sed "s/\/bin\///" | sed "s/\/usr//")
[ -z "$de" ] && de=$(echo $XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP)
[ -z "$terminal" ] && terminal=$(readlink "/proc/$(cat /proc/$(echo $$)/stat|cut -d ' ' -f 4)/exe")

printf "$USER@$host\n"
printf "OS           $os\n"
printf "Kernel       $kernel\n"
printf "Uptime       $uptime\n"
printf "Shell        $shell\n"
printf "DE           $de\n"
printf "Terminal     $terminal\n"
if [ "$colorsoff" != 1 ]; then
    printf "\033[0;31m● \033[0;32m● \033[0;33m● \033[0;34m● \033[0;35m● \033[0;36m● \033[0;37m●\033[0m\n"
fi



I can't reproduce the "work perfectly fine" part. As a regular user I don't get any output (because of a "permission denied" in an intermediate step), and as root I get sudo as the "terminal emulator".

Aside: $(echo $$) is the same as just $$. In general, $(echo something) is the same as just something

I don't think there's a robust way to do this. You need to walk the process hierarchy until you get to the terminal emulator, but there's no standard way to tell which process that is. There's nothing special that distinguishes an emulator from other processes.

The terminal emulator might not even be running on this system. If you use SSH to login to the system, the emulator is on the client system.

could the $TERM environment variable be of any help?

Have a look at Get Window ID from process ID

@StefenHegney it returns a generic name like xterm-256color

Knowing the terminal capabilities (columns, lines, number of supported colours) is probably more useful than known the emulator executable name. tput canl tell you all about those capabilities. Example printf %s\\n cols lines colors | tput -S | xargs printf 'Terminal is %d×%d characters and supports %d colors!\n'

Why do you want the terminal emulator? (in most cases, infocmp or tput is what you want - at least if you want to know how to render stuff)

Generally, it is impossible to do. The only best efforted way you can traverse the pid hierarchy up until you find a terminal emulator from a known list.
The following looks ok. Add more terminals to the list you want to handle.
terminals="konsole xterm etc.."  # space separated list of terminal emulators
terminal=unknown
cur=$$
while cur=$(ps -o ppid:1= -p "$cur") && ((cur)); do
  comm=$(<"/proc/$cur/comm")
  if [[ " $terminals " = *" $comm "* ]]; then
    terminal=$comm
    break
  fi
done
echo "$terminal"

